# Numpy repack_fields with range or a list allocates memory

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, structured-array

### Issue:

I am trying to repack a subset of rows and fields from a large numpy structured array.

When I use a slice, I am able to use `repack_fields`, but when I use a `range` I am not. Calling
`range` before `repack_fields` appears to be allocating all of the memory needed by the original array.

### Example:

Below is an example where I limit the available memory in order to introduce the error I am observing my use case.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import repack_fields
import resource

resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (int(1.5e9), int(1.5e9)))

H = np.zeros(100, dtype=[('f1', int), ('f2', int), ('large', float, 1000000)])

print('Using slicing: ')
repack_fields(H[['f1', 'f2']][0:50])
print('Using range: ')
repack_fields(H[['f1', 'f2']][range(0, 50)])
```

produces the output:

```
Using slicing: 
Using range: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    repack_fields(H[['f1', 'f2']][range(0, 50)])
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 381. MiB for an array with shape (50,) and data type {'names':['f1','f2'], 'formats':['<i8','<i8'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':8000016}
```

### Questions:

1. Why is the behavior of `range(0, 50)` different than `0:50`? (A list also doesn't work.) I know in the above example, one could repack the fields first, and then reference the rows. (That is, `repack_fields(H[['f1', 'f2']])[range(0, 50)]` works.) But I don't want to have to know whether it is better to get rows first or fields first.
2. What is the correct way to take a subset of rows/fields from a large numpy structured array? (even when the rows are not consecutive)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
repack_fields(H[['f1', 'f2']][0:50])
```

Both `[['f1', 'f2']]` and `[0:50]` produce a `view`, one because it's a multifield index, and the other because it's a slice (basic indexing).  So that doesn't require new memory.  `repack_fields` makes a new array with space for just those 2 fields, and 50 records, and copies values from the `view`.

```
repack_fields(H[['f1', 'f2']][range(0, 50)])
```

Again the fields index is a `view`, referencing the whole structure, including the `large` field.  `[range...]` is advanced indexing, making a copy that includes 50 records of 'large'.

Look at the error:

```
 Unable to allocate 381. MiB for an array with shape (50,) and data type
 {'names':['f1','f2'], 'formats':['<i8','<i8'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':8000016}

 In [336]: 50*8000016/1e6
 Out[336]: 400.0008
```

There's the 381 MB that it's trying to allocate.  The error occurs in the `[range(50)]` indexing.  It hasn't gotten to the repack yet.

So you have to understand two things.

- Indexing with a slice makes a `view` that does not consume added memory.  Indexing with `range` or list (or array) is 'advanced indexing' and makes a copy.
- multifield indexing makes a `view`.  Even if the fields are a subset of the source, the itemsize is still the original size.  The purpose of `repack` is to make a new array with new dtype and new itemsize, containing just the values for the selected fields.

Comment: Do you know the correct way to grab a subset of (nonconsecutive) rows as a view?

Comment: There isn't one.  A view is only possible when memory is consecutive or can be identified with strides (as with a slice with step).  That's the case for all arrays.